# How to fix the alignment of the slider text with logo?

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am working on a rev slider on word press. I align text with logo in 1300px resolution screen but when it comes to 1500px or larger, text and logo alignment change. How to fix this problem?

[image: Slider in 1300px resolution]

[image: Slider in 1500px and big screen]

Comment: means do you need slider display always same width in all screens?

Comment: yeah this text is move when we see in larger screen

Comment: improved wording

Comment: As far as I now you can edit the position of layers in Revolution Slider for different widths of the screen. Try checking this out - https://www.themepunch.com/faq/incorrect-position-or-size-for-text-button-or-shape/